# Converting SWFs to mac .app

Tags: macos, actionscript-3, flash

I'm putting together a program that runs on the desktop rather than being an online program.  There are relatively easy ways (http://swf-to-exe.com/) to do that for Windows.  Now I need to put together something for Macs.  I asked this before and got some good hints which I am now pursuing.  This [page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f709e16db131e43659b9-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f-63d4a6d6131f383b813-8000) was recommended.

Can somebody explain what this means?  I find adt.bat and adt.jar files, but I am clueless as to what these directions are telling me to do:

```
adt -package 
    -keystore ../cert.p12 -storetype pkcs12 
    -target bundle 
    myApp.app 
    myApp-app.xml 
    myApp.swf icons resources
```

I've been doing many searches for information about this but haven't found it.

Here are the instructions I got from Jeff Ward in [this question:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004452/converting-swfs-to-exes)

> In Flash Develop, I created an "AIR AS3 Projector" type project named
>   DesktopTest. I then modified the Packager.bat file according to the
>   article I posted above. Change the OUTPUT and call adt lines and leave
>   the other lines of the file in-tact:
>
> set OUTPUT=-target bundle %AIR_NAME% And:
>
> call adt -package %OPTIONS% %SIGNING_OPTIONS% %OUTPUT% %APP_XML%
>   %FILE_OR_DIR% You then need to run CreateCertificate.bat once
>   (right-click, execute). After that, compile your project and run
>   PackageApp.bat. For my project named DesktopTest, this results in a
>   DesktopTest sub directory that is my compiled app, with a
>   DesktopTest.exe in it.

That part makes sense.  What I don't understand is how to deal with the information from Adobe.  I'm sure it's simple, but this is an area I haven't dealt with much and I'm drawing a blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got the following from Phillipe, the admin on the FlashDevelop discussion board:

> Yes AIR allows you to package a SWF into an application.
>
> This isn't simple though and everything has to be done through the
>   command line.  You'll have to search quite a bit to figure how things
>   work but that's quite powerful.

It looks like this is not well documented.  If anybody knows of a good place for documentation, please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Quick google search brought up this: http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/#Download it works for both Mac OS X and Windows.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of Zinc.  High cost, tried asking questions of their support team recently and got no answers.  That's not a good solution.

Comment: Ah fair enough. Have you tried AIR? I heard that was quite good for things like this.

Comment: Yes, I am using FlashDevelop to put together an AIR AS3 Projector. However, I have not been able to find clear instructions on how to turn the .SWF into an .app.  The one set I found is, at least to me, completely obscure.  Clearly there's something I don't understand, and that's why I'm asking.

Comment: Actually there is one more problem with Zinc. For reasons which are not obvious it is not playing the audio in the program.  I sent several messages to their support team and got no answer.